# "A" and not "U.S." as a keyboard layout indicator. How to change it to "U.S."?

Tags: macos, language

I use two keyboard layouts on my Mac, U.S. and Russian. For some reason, the U.S. layout in indicated by `A`, not `U.S.`. Why is it so? How is it possible to have `U.S.` there instead of `A`?

[image]

Screenshot for Ruskes:

[image]

Comment: I think you need to have another Latin keyboard on the list to have it show US.  The idea may be that the layout is for a language rather than a country

Comment: Go to Open Keyboard Settings  keyboard > Input sources and select US, then remove the English (A)

Answer (score 1):

For it to show US you need to select the US and the US International

[image: select]

**Not the A for ABC**

[image]

Comment: Hi, Ruskes. Sorry for a long reply, I wasn't at home. For some reason, I don't have **`US` U.S.** option. What I have is **`A` U.S.** instead. I have added the screenshot to the question.

Comment: @jsx97 OK, select English on the left, then scroll down on the right window till US and select that